# Volume Button (Lumia 535)

Tags: settings, camera, functionality, buttons

My device is a Lumia 535. It has a about 5 inch screen. This makes it a bit difficult to take selfies  because you have to click the click option to take a picture. Isn't there a feature of clicking a picture with the help of the volume button. Is this only with my device or is it the same for such a model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to suggest an easier option to counteract the need of pressing the screen, which often results in blurry or shaky photos.

Go under the Lumia Camera and switch to the front camera, then click the gear icon to view the camera `settings`, then under that, you will see a `timer` option:

[image]

Change the option to the number of seconds you prefer.

Alternatively, you can download the [Lumia Selfie](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/store/apps/Lumia-Selfie/9WZDNCRDZZ4P) app, which virtually has the same option of taking selfies using a timer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can take photos while taping anywhere on screen. such a feature is available on inbuilt camera app as well as on lumia camera. i guess, its more easier than pressing volume down button. give it a try

Comment: The inbuilt camera app does not support this feature you are saying.

Comment: Yeah...."I can't tap anywhere on the screen to take photo" for inbuilt camera app on my 535 as well. Please rectify it.